# Django: ManyToMany Field on a model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I have these models:

```
class Unit(AppModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Item(AppModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    units = models.ManyToManyField("Unit", symmetrical=False, related_name="items")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + self.units

class Invoice(AppModel):
    items = models.ManyToManyField("Item", symmetrical=False, related_name="invoices")

    def __str__(self):
        return "invoice_" + self.id
```

As you can see, we have an `Item` with multiple `units` and an `Invoice` with multiple `items`.

But, I want each `item` in an `Invoice` to have a single `unit` only. How to achieve that?

i.e, `some_item.units` should return all its type of units. Whereas, `for item in some_invoice.items: return item.units` should return a single unit.

Is there any other way to implement it? A new database design?? Then How? Help..

**Note**: I was not able to frame the title of this Post. Feel free to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need a ForeignKey to Unit on your Item model, not a ManyToManyField. That way an item will have only one unit, but a unit will be allowed to have multiple items.

Comment: Yours doesn't answer my question. The Item must have multiple Units. But the item when pointed to by an invoice must have a single unit.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your item relation to ForeignKey

```
class Item(AppModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    units = models.ForeignKey(Unit, related_name="items")
```

**Update**

Set your invoice model between Unit and Item.

```
class Item(AppModel):
    units = models.ManyToManyField(Unit, through='Invoice')

class Unit(AppModel):
    ...

class Invoice(AppModel):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='invoice')
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit, related_name='invoice')
```

Comment: Sorry, But please read the question carefully. The `Item` must have a `many` `units`. But the item when pointed to by an `invoice` should have only one `unit`. I am aware of `ForeignKey`.

Comment: How can it return single unit. Any parameter or requirements from your business process? Because if we see database design, ideally it return many units. So either you change database design (ie:add another table) or change its relation.

Comment: I'm not sure is this what you're looking for. But maybe the easy way is you should filter its units

`for item in some_invoice.items:
    if .... 
    return a unit
`

Comment: Exactly. I am looking for a new database design. But not another table.

Comment: But there is something else. The Unit of the Invoice Item must be one of the units of the items.

Comment: I think you should do that using ORM

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need I think.

```
class Unit(AppModel):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.name

class Item(AppModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    units = models.ManyToManyField("Unit", symmetrical=False, 
            related_name="items", through='ItemUnit')

    def __str__(self):
       return self.title + self.units

class ItemUnit(AppModel):
   item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
   unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit)

   def __str__(self):
     return "%s --- %s " % (self.item, self.unit)

class Invoice(AppModel):
    item_unit = models.ForeignKey(ItemUnit, blank=True, null=True, 
    related_name='invoices', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

In the above setup, Item-Unit-Invoice is always a unique combination. Make sure you specify on_delete for the many-to-many FK.

Comment: Thanks. I know that. But `Invoice` has an `item` as a ForeignKey. And `item_unit` should be one of the units of current instance of item.

Comment: In your question, Invoice has a many-to-many with Item and Item has a many-to-many with Units. I don't see another way around unless you change your schema structure.